# What is the default animation step in Mathematica?

Tags: animation

I have a simple question about animation: if you do not specify the animation step, what value is used?

Thank you.

Comment: Which animation function are you referring to?  Display within the Notebook or as export to another format like `.GIF`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this test to verify the use of this function:

One frame every 0.5 seconds:

```
g = Graphics[
    Table[{Text[Style[#, FontSize -> 40, Bold, Red], {0, 0}]}, 1]] & /@
   Range[10] ; Export["C:\Users\LMC\Documents\anima.gif", g, 
 "DisplayDurations" -> 0.5]
```

One frame every 1 seconds:

```
g = Graphics[
    Table[{Text[Style[#, FontSize -> 40, Bold, Red], {0, 0}]}, 1]] & /@
   Range[10] ; Export["C:\Users\LMC\Documents\anima.gif", g, 
 "DisplayDurations" -> 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for Animate, the `DefaultDuration` parameter has value   5 (the default duration in seconds) though you can change this by using the option `DefaultDuration->s` to set it to `s` seconds.